# In Java, removing many character of a string

Tags: java, string, substring

In java, I want remove character of a string - this is my source code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Let's challenge in my favorite language!!
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Integer n = line.length();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                line = line.substring(i);
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

i have input a string

> PXaeiTzVap

then i want result

> Paiza

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to remove every second character.

I'd use a for-loop for this:

```
String out = "";
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i += 2)
{
    out += line.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Notice that I add `2` to `i`. So it should get the char 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.

And thus, it will result in "Paiza".

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop backwards through the String, and either do String addition, or use a StringBuilder

```
    String line = "PXaeiTzVap";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
    for(int i = line.length() - 1; i > 0; i--){
        if( i%2 == 0 )
        {
           sb.delete(i-1, i);
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

This will print out *Paizap*

Answer (score 0):

```
public String removeEveryOtherChar(String line) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result += String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(line.length()/2);
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i+= 2) {
    out.append(line.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use a for loop to iterate over each character of the string. For each character, convert to a lower case using `Character.toLowerCase(char a)` method and compare with the original char. If they are unequal then it means that the char there must be an upper case letter and thus must be removed. Remove it by taking a substring of all the characters before that char and after that char and adding the substrings to set the string with a new string object that excludes the unwanted character. Make sure to do `i--` because the size of the string changes and you don't want to skip the char that is now in the place of the one you just removed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    if( Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) != str.charAt(i) )
    {
        str = str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1);
        i--;
    }
}
```